# How can I scrape sites that require authentication using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, web-scraping

I've come across many [tutorials explaining how to scrape public websites that don't require authentication/login](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-scrape-web-pages-with-node-js-and-jquery/), using node.js.

Can somebody explain how to scrape sites that require login using node.js?

Comment: did you get this working? Please post a code sample if you did.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scraping a website which requires authentication using node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765525/scraping-a-website-which-requires-authentication-using-node-js)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [Mikeal's Request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) library, you need to enable cookies support like this:

```
var request = request.defaults({jar: true})
```

So you first should create a username on that site (manually) and pass the username and the password as params when making the POST request to that site. After that the server will respond with a cookie which Request will remember, so you will be able to access the pages that require you to be logged into that site.

Note: this approach doesn't work if something like reCaptcha is used on the login page.

Comment: @ alessioalex Thank you. I will try your suggestion and update the status here.

Comment: Can you please provide me any sample of how to do that I am doing that as you said but with no luck I am trying to scrap an asp.net site.

Comment: It would be useful if you post a code sample somewhere (a gist or something), so I can figure out what you're doing wrong. It would be faster this way.

Comment: @alessioalex +1 please provide a full example

Comment: If the target website uses CSRF protection, you can try [csrf-login](https://github.com/bahmutov/csrf-login).

Comment: and what if cookie is expired on server? you need to request fresh one and inject into your code again and again. it is not convenient

Answer (score 13):

I've been working with NodeJs Scrapers for **more than 2 years now**

I can tell you that the best choice when dealing with logins and authentication is to NOT use direct request

That is because you just waste time on building manual requests and it is way slower,

Instead, use a high lever browser that you control via an API like [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) or [NightmareJs](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare)

I have a good starter and in-depth guide on [**How to start scraping with Puppeteer**](https://learnscraping.com/nodejs-web-scraping-with-puppeteer/), I'm sure it will help!

Comment: I'm agree with you.

Comment: I agree with you

Answer (score 9):

Or using [superagent](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent):

```
var superagent = require('superagent')
var agent = superagent.agent();
```

`agent` is then a [persistent browser](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#preserving-cookie), which will handle getting and setting cookies, referers, etc. Just `agent.get`, `agent.post()` as normal.

Comment: Do you have sources / doc for agent? I couldn't find any on http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent

Answer (score 3):

You can **scrape the data from sites that require authentication** like **csrf token**.

Using the **cookies** for each request like this:

```
var j = request.jar(); // this is to set the jar of request for session and cookie persistence

request = request.defaults({ jar: j }); //here we are setting the default cookies of request
```

Here is small code to elaborate it further:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var request = require('request'); //npm request package to send a get and post request to a url
const cheerio = require('cheerio'); //npm package used for scraping content from third party sites
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());

var _csrf; //variable to store the _csrf value to be used later

app.use(bodyParser.json());
var html = '';

var j = request.jar(); // this is to set the jar of request for session and cookie persistence
request = request.defaults({ jar: j }); //here we are setting the default cookies of request


//___________________API CALL TO VERIFY THE GMS NUMBER_______________________
app.get('/check', function(req, response) {

    var schemeId = null;
    if (req.query.schemeId) {
        schemeId = req.query.schemeId;
        console.log(schemeId);

    } else {
        response.send('false');
        response.end();
    }
    getCsrfValue(function(err, res) {
        if (!err) {
            _csrf = res;
            console.log(_csrf);

            request.post({
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': '',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                },
                uri: 'https://www.xyz.site',

                body: "schemeId=" + schemeId + "&_csrf=" + _csrf

            }, function(err, res, body) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("body of post: " + res.body);

                    const $ = cheerio.load(body.toString());
                    var txt = $('.schemeCheckResult').text();

                    console.log(txt);
                    if (txt) {
                        response.send('true');
                    } else {

                        response.send('false');
                    }
                    html += body;
                }
            });

        } else {
            response.send(err);
        }

    })


});

//______________FUNCTION TO SCRAPE THE CSRF TOKEN FROM THE SITE____________
function getCsrfValue(callback) {
    request.get({
        headers: {
            'Authorization': '',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        uri: 'https://www.xyz.site'

    }, function(err, res, body) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        } else {
            const $ = cheerio.load(body.toString());
            var txt = $('input[name=_csrf]').val();
            _csrf = txt;

            return callback(null, _csrf);
        }
    });

}

module.exports = app;
```