# How application on Node JS can go to a third-party site that requires authentication?

Tags: node.js, authentication, postman, cheerio

Requires login to the third-party server and gain access to content for authorized users.

PhantomJS not suitable.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var credentials = {
    username: 'user',
    password: 'pass'
};

request.post({
    uri: 'http://mysite.ru/login',
    headers: { 'content–type': 'application/x–www–form–urlencoded' },
    body: require('querystring').stringify(credentials)
}, function(err, res, body){
    if(err) {
        callback.call(null, new Error(' Login failed'));
        return;
    }

    request('http://mysite.ru/all', function(err, res, body) {
        if(err) {
            callback.call(null, new Error('Request failed'));
            return;
        }

        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        console.log(body);
    });
});
```

But the output html code gives the same login page.

I do not ask to edit my code, but perhaps someone will point the nose in the correct lesson? Preferably in conjunction with PostMan - ohm (to be able to analyzing standard browser requests and use them in their requests from the application)

UPDATE!!!
SOLVED:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
**var request = request.defaults({jar: true})**
var credentials = {
    username: 'user',
    password: 'pass'
};

request.post({
    uri: 'http://mysite.ru/login',
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
      body: require('querystring').stringify(credentials),
        headers: {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
}, function(err, res, body){
    if(err) {
        callback.call(null, new Error(' Login  failed'));
        return;
    }

    request('http://mysite.ru/all', function(err, res, body) {
        if(err) {
            callback.call(null, new Error('Request failed'));
            return;
        }

        var $ =  cheerio .load(body);

        console.log(body);
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you need to enable cookie support: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8726464/5230117

Comment: Thanks! Work well 4 me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
**var request = request.defaults({jar: true})**
var credentials = {
    username: 'user',
    password: 'pass'
};

request.post({
    uri: 'http://mysite.ru/login',
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
      body: require('querystring').stringify(credentials),
        headers: {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
}, function(err, res, body){
    if(err) {
        callback.call(null, new Error(' Login  failed'));
        return;
    }

    request('http://mysite.ru/all', function(err, res, body) {
        if(err) {
            callback.call(null, new Error('Request failed'));
            return;
        }

        var $ =  cheerio.load(body);

        console.log(body);
    });
});
```