# How to get login into a website using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I want to scrape data from an authentication website, but unable to get any result. I try with the code bellow:

```
var j = request.jar();
var request = request.defaults({jar : j})
request({
    url:'http://jobs.phnomlist.com/login',
    method:'POST',
    form:{email:"xxxx",password:"xxxxx"}
}, function(){
    request('http://jobs.phnomlist.com/dashboard', function(error, response, body){
        if(!error && response.statusCode==200){
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);

            var data = $('.x_panel').html();
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

What did I miss in the code?

Please help me. Really thankful for help.

Comment: Where are you getting an error?

Comment: are you getting any error or response in the 2nd request function?

Comment: I don't get any errors and don't get any result

Comment: @DooDoo: You're not "get[ting] any errors" because your code isn't checking for errors. Remember that the Node convention is that first argument of a callback is an error. By not checking that, you're ignoring errors.

Comment: Try looking at this answer as it may help you a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726079/how-can-i-scrape-sites-that-require-authentication-using-node-js

Comment: @Alex I have follow that link already, but still can't

Comment: @DooDoo Write `if(error) { console.log(error) }` to log error

Comment: @CodingDefined still no error exist

Comment: @DooDoo Log the `response.statusCode` before checking that it is 200

Comment: Still have not error, but in that website i got this->Status Code:302 Found