# Nodejs web scraping from Ecommerce platforms' search results

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, jsdom

I'm learning to scrape search results from e-commerce platforms(Ebay, etc...) with nodeJS.

The problem I'm facing is that there are sponsored products in these platforms;
such that these sponsored items will appear together with other non-sponsored but keyword-relevant items in the search result page.

When I use Postman to check the API responsible for the search results,
it appears that only the `non-sponsored but relevant items` can be retrieved from that API called.
As a result, simply calling API is not workable in this case as I also wanna scrape those sponsored items as well.

I would like to ask:
using nodeJS, how to scrape both sponsored and non-sponsored items appeared in the search result page?
I'm thinking about using certain packages such as jsdom or puppeteer, may I ask if my thought is on the right track? Thx a lots!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I scrape sites that require authentication using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726079/how-can-i-scrape-sites-that-require-authentication-using-node-js)

Comment: puppeteer would be right tool for this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should  send GET requests with axios or etc. and then parse the whole webpage using puppeteer or REGEX , you are on the right path